# ¿Cómo representar respuestas correctas e incorrectas en casillas verdes y blanca desde una base de datos?

Tags: php, html, sql, css

Estaba planteando representar las respuestas de 252 preguntas de un test en un cuadro de manera que las casillas verdes son las preguntas que han sido respondidas correctamente y tienen el valor 1 en la columna "respuestasCorrectas" de la tabla "respuestasUsuarios" y si tiene el valor 0 (es decir incorrecto) en la tabla "respuestasCorrectas", entonces representar en color blanco.

Quedaría de siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si sería lo más adecuado hacer una consulta que devuelva mediantte un fetchrow los valores 0 ó 1 en un array, y despuestas representar el cuadro de la imagen recorriendo el array.
Tampoco estoy seguro si representar esos cuadros con DIVs con altura y anchura, o si subir una imagen verde.jpg y blanco.jpg, de manera que si el valor del array es 1, mostrar verde.jpg y si es valor 0 representar la imagen blanco.jpg.

¿Cómo lo plantearías como método más eficaz?
(No pido código, sino planteamiento aproximado)

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Todo lo que decis es correcto, entonces es una pregunta totalmente basada en opiniones. No tiene una respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he conseguido, y de esta manera:

```
echo "<div style='width:100%;'>";
$contador=0;
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$consulta))
{
  // Fetch one and one row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM))
    {
        $contador++;
    //echo $row[0]."<br>";
        if($row[0]==0){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";

        }
        if($row[0]==1){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.2); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==2){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.4); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==3){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 0.6); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";
        }   
        if($row[0]==4){
            echo "<div title='".$contador."' style='background-color:rgba(26, 194, 0, 1); width:20px;height:20px;float:left;border-style: solid;border-width:1px;border-color:lightgrey;'></div>";

        }
    }
}

echo "</div>";

Da como resultado esto (en este caso se ha hecho con 5 valores[0-4], cada uno un color):
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]